# Python から s3 にプロキシ経由でのアクセス時に発生するエラーを解決したい

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

S3へアクセスする際に例外エラーが発生してアクセスできません。
対処方法などあれば教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

プロキシ周りの設定を変更する必要があるのかその辺りの知見がなく、アドバイス頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

**実行環境**

ネットワーク: 社内ネットワーク
Windows10 Pro
Python 3.7.9
各パッケージ

```
Package         Version
boto3           1.16.25
botocore        1.19.25
jmespath        0.10.0
pip             20.2.4
python-dateutil 2.8.1
s3transfer      0.3.3
selenium        3.141.0
setuptools      47.1.0
six             1.15.0
urllib3         1.26.2
wheel           0.35.1
```

#### 発生している例外エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 502, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 429, in ssl_wrap_socket
    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 263, in send
    chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 506, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 502, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 429, in ssl_wrap_socket
    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054, '既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    Prefix='sample/'
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 663, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 682, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 256, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 285, in send
    raise ProxyConnectionError(proxy_url=proxy_url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "https://Proxy:8080"
```

#### コード

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.list_objects(
    Bucket='bucket001',
    Prefix='sample/'
)

for item in response['Contents']:
    print('{} : {}'.format(item['Key'],item['LastModified']))
```

Comment: `Failed to connect to proxy URL: "https://Proxy:8080"` と表示されていますので、プロキシサーバの設定(環境変数 `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` の設定内容)を確認するとよろしいかと思います。

Comment: metropolisさん早速コメントありがとうございます！確認します m(__)m

Comment: metropolisさん、HTTP_PROXYにproxy URLを設定することでアクセスできました！本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージに `Failed to connect to proxy URL: "https://Proxy:8080"` と表示されているので、プロキシサーバの設定 (環境変数 `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` の設定内容) を確認し、必要に応じて設定を追加してみてください。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72332/python%e3%81%a7s3%e3%81%b8%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab%e7%99%ba%e7%94%9f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment80309_72332) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*